# Shuffling Mongodb docs using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking for a way to sort my Mongodb documents in a random order.

I couldn't find any solution on PyMongo's API or StackOverflow.

A list based solution or any other memory consuming solution is irrelevant because I'm working with massive dbs.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not have a "sort by random" feature. If you have few enough documents to fit in RAM you can fetch them all into a list and use the Python standard library's `random.shuffle`:

```
import random
import pymongo

collection = pymongo.MongoClient().db.collection
docs = random.shuffle(list(collection.find()))
```

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for, I want to work with a stream and not use the memory because I'm working with massive loads of data. Iv'e edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on end result you are trying to achieve probably [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) 
aggregation operator will do the job.

```
cursor = your_collection.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': your_collection.count()}}], allowDiskUse=True)
```

This will give you a random aggregation cursor which you can iterate

```
for document in cursor:
     print (document)
```

- For exact behavior read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)
- Another (complicated) alternative can be a map/reduce job where you can emit a random number along the rest of the document then sort by this.

Comment: It says in the documentation $sample might select same document more than once and in addition there are some demands such as:
- N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
- The collection contains more than 100 documents

So I think this method is less relevant for my task.

Comment: You are wrong 
1) $sample will NOT select same document more than once, this possibility exists only if you modify a document during the operation (see cursor isolation) 
2) Even if N > 5% still you will get random documents via a random sort - i.e: the method changes end result is same.